# Upload a file to the file structure, form data to the database

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload, insert

Due-diligence done, once again I return to the experts. Please forgive my ignorance, new to all this.

I'm trying to create a form which allows users to:

- Insert the values of various form fields into a mysql database table - Easy, no issues here.
- Attach a file which is saved within the file structure (in a folder called 'documents').
- Save the file name, size, type (pdf, txt, etc.) to the same record.

After a file is uploaded the table would contain:

- id (auto incremented)
- name (text field, user generated)
- description (text field, user generated)
- File name (e.g. text.txt, added automatically on upload)
- File size (e.g. 362455[kb], added automatically on upload)
- File type (e.g. pdf, added automatically on upload)

I've successfully saved files to the folder but have not been able to make my three requirements a reality... Despite hours or troubleshoot and Googling.

The database and form are correct, the php file I post to is the mystery. Any ideas?

```
<form method="post" id="addForm" action="includes/insert_news.php">                   
<table class="addForm" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <th>Name:<span class="greenText">*</span></th>
    <td><input name="name" type="text" class="textBox required" value="Friendly Document Name" maxlength="80" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Description:<span class="greenText">*</span></th>
    <td><textarea name="description" class="textBox required">Document description blah blah</textarea></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>File:</th>
    <td><input name="file" class="textBox" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>&nbsp;</th>
    <td><input type="image" class="button" src="images/button_submit.gif" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you post the code for the includes/insert_news.php file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have already added the missing thing @shakti pointed out, and you change the `<input>` by adding `type="file"` and since you didn't give any information about your php code, try these out:

```
<?php
class UploadFile{

//declare some variables in corresponding to your database field here, like fields, table name and stuffs

public function attach_file($file) {
    if($file['error'] != 0) {
        //do something
    } else {
        $this->temp_path    = $file['tmp_name'];
        $path_parts         = pathinfo($file['name']);
        $this->filename     = $path_parts['extension'];// to get the filename
        $this->type         = $file['type'];// to get the file type
        $this->size         = $file['size'];// to get the size
        $this->name         = $name;
        $this->description  = $description;
    }
}


public function save() {        
    $target_path = "/some/folder";
    if(move_uploaded_file($this->temp_path, $target_path)) {
        if($this->create()) {
            unset($this->temp_path);
            return true;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public function create() {
    //your INSERT INTO
}
?>
```

and in your insert_news.php :

```
<?php
require_once("class/location");
if($_FILES['file']) {
    $news = new UploadFile();
    $news->attach_file($_FILES['main_picture'], $_POST['name'], $_POST['description']);
    if($pic->save()){
        //do something
    }
}
?>
```

haven't tested this, but i hope you get the point :D

Answer (score 1):

I am wondering you said that

> I've successfully saved files to the
>   folder but

but I think you are not getting anything in the `$_FILES` because this thing is missing in your `form tag`

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
```